# Find combination of n vectors across k dataframes with highest correlation

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, correlation

Let's assume four data frames, each with 3 vectors, e.g.

```
setA <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(6,5,2,4,5,3,4,4,5,3),
  a2 = c(4,3,1,4,5,1,1,6,3,2),
  a3 = c(5,4,5,6,4,6,5,5,3,3)
)

setB <- data.frame(
  b1 = c(5,3,4,3,3,6,4,4,3,5),
  b2 = c(4,3,1,3,5,2,5,2,5,6),
  b3 = c(6,5,4,3,2,6,4,3,4,6)
)

setC <- data.frame(
  c1 = c(4,4,5,5,6,4,2,2,4,6),
  c2 = c(3,3,4,4,2,1,2,3,5,4),
  c3 = c(4,5,4,3,5,5,3,5,5,6)
)

setD <- data.frame(
  d1 = c(5,5,4,4,3,5,3,5,5,4),
  d2 = c(4,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,5),
  d3 = c(6,5,5,3,3,4,2,5,5,4)
)
```

I'm trying to find `n` number of vectors in each data frame, that have the highest correlation **among each other**. For this simple example, let's say want to find the `n = 1` vectors in each of the `k = 4` data frames, that show the overall strongest, positive correlation `cor()`.

I'm not interested in the correlation of vectors within a data frame, but the correlation between data frames, since i wish to pick 1 variable from each set.

Intuitively, I would sum all the correlation coefficients for each combination, i.e.:

```
sum(cor(cbind(setA$a1, setB$b1, setC$c1, setC$d1)))
sum(cor(cbind(setA$a1, setB$b2, setC$c1, setC$d1)))
sum(cor(cbind(setA$a1, setB$b1, setC$c2, setC$d1)))
... # and so on...
```

...but this seems like brute-forcing a solution that might be solvable more elegantly, with some kind of clustering-technique?

Anyhow, I was hoping to find a dynamic solution like `function(n = 1, ...)` where (`...` for data frames) which would return a list of the highest correlating vector names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your example I would not go with a really complicated algorithm unless your actual data is huge. This is a simple approach I think gets what you want. 
So base on your 4 data frames a creates the `list_df` and then in the function I just generate all the possible combinations of variables an calculate their correlation. At the end I select the n combinations with highest correlation.

```
list_df = list(setA,setB,setC,setD)

CombMaxCor = function(n = 1,list_df){

  column_names = lapply(list_df,colnames)
  mat_comb     = expand.grid(column_names)
  mat_total    = do.call(cbind,list_df)
  vec_cor      = rep(NA,nrow(mat_comb))

  for(i in 1:nrow(mat_comb)){
    vec_cor[i] = sum(cor(mat_total[,as.character(unlist(mat_comb[i,]))]))
  }
  pos_max_temp = rev(sort(vec_cor))[1:n]
  pos_max      = vec_cor%in%pos_max_temp
  comb_max_cor = mat_comb[pos_max,]
  return(comb_max_cor)
}
```

Comment: This works perfect with my example, thanks! :) My real data hast 4 dataframes with 20 vectors each, so naturally it takes quite some time to process. If anything comes to mind on how performance could be increased, I'm happy to hear it. THanks alot

Comment: @ComfortEagle i think replacing the `for` with an `apply` might make it faster or paralellizing the for would also help

Answer (score 2):

You could use `comb` function:

```
fun = function(x){
  nm = paste0(names(x),collapse="")
  if(!grepl("(.)\\d.*\\1",nm,perl = T))
    setNames(sum(cor(x)),nm)
}
unlist(combn(a,4,fun,simplify = FALSE))[1:3]#Only printed the first 3

a1b1c1d1 a1b1c1d2 a1b1c1d3 
3.246442 4.097532 3.566949 

sum(cor(cbind(setA$a1, setB$b1, setC$c1, setD$d1)))
[1] 3.246442
sum(cor(cbind(setA$a1, setB$b1, setC$c1, setD$d2)))
[1] 4.097532
sum(cor(cbind(setA$a1, setB$b1, setC$c1, setD$d3)))
[1] 3.566949
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function we can use to get n non-repeating columns from each data frame to get the max total correlation:

```
func <- function(n, ...){

    list.df <- list(...)
    n.df <- length(list.df)


    # 1) First get the correlations
    get.two.df.cors <- function(df1, df2) apply(df1, 2, 
        function(x) apply(df2, 2, function(y) cor(x,y))
        )
    cor.combns <-  lapply(list.df, function(x) 
        lapply(list.df, function(y) get.two.df.cors(x,y))
        )


    # 2) Define function to help with aggregating the correlations.
    # We will call them for different combinations of selected columns from each df later

    # cmbns: given a df corresponding columns to be selected each data frame
    # (i-th row corresponds to i-th df),
    # return the "total correlation"


    get.cmbn.sum <- function(cmbns, cor.combns){
        # a helper matrix to help aggregation
        # each row represents which two data frames we want to get the correlation sums
        df.df <- t(combn(seq(n.df), 2, c))

        # convert to list of selections for each df
        cmbns <- split(cmbns, seq(nrow(cmbns)))

        sums <- apply(df.df, 1,
          function(dfs) sum(
             cor.combns[[dfs[1]]][[dfs[2]]][cmbns[[dfs[2]]], cmbns[[dfs[1]]]] 
          )
        )

        # sum of the sums give the "total correlation"
        sum(sums)
    }



    # 3) Now perform the aggragation

    # get the methods of choosing n columns from each of the k data frames
    if (n==1) {
    cmbns.each.df <- lapply(list.df, function(df) matrix(seq(ncol(df)), ncol=1))
    } else {
    cmbns.each.df <- lapply(list.df, function(df) t(combn(seq(ncol(df)), n, c)))
    }

    # get all unique selection methods
    unique.selections <- Reduce(function(all.dfs, new.df){
        all.dfs.lst <- rep(list(all.dfs), nrow(new.df))
        all.new.rows <- lapply(seq(nrow(new.df)), function(x) new.df[x,,drop=F])
        for(i in seq(nrow(new.df))){
            for(j in seq(length(all.dfs.lst[[i]]))){
                all.dfs.lst[[i]][[j]] <- rbind(all.dfs.lst[[i]][[j]], all.new.rows[[i]])
            }
        }

        do.call(c, all.dfs.lst)

    }, c(list(list(matrix(numeric(0), nrow=0, ncol=n))), cmbns.each.df))

    # for each unique selection method, calculate the total correlation
    result <- sapply(unique.selections, get.cmbn.sum, cor.combns=cor.combns)
    return( unique.selections[[which.max(result)]] )

}
```

And now we have:

```
# n = 1
func(1, setA, setB, setC, setD)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    2

# n = 2
func(2, setA, setB, setC, setD)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    3
# [3,]    2    3
# [4,]    2    3
```